# How to get out of "Select Boot Mode" screen on ONN tablet?

Tags: boot, bootloader

When I power on my ONN tablet, I come to the "Select Boot Mode" screen.

[image]

The arrow moves up and down by itself, and I am unable to make a selection.  I've changed the power button hardware and it still does it.  I have also tried holding down the power and volume up.  It resets, but comes back to this screen.

Is there perhaps something wrong with the hardware?

Comment: hello so i see this problem u need a computer to fix this problem u need to install a flasher may i know ur model?

Comment: "*The arrow moves up and down by itself*" seems to hint that a possible problem is with the volume button stuck, thus it always reboots to this screen...